# Android: How to make scale animation does not change text in button

Tags: android

I have a scale animation, it will change a button from `0.5 to 1`, but at the same time the `text in the button` will be gradually `enlarged`, how to keep the `text` as it is？
Tried to dynamically change the `width` of the `button`, but the effect is not good

Comment: Instead of using button UI, You have to use FrameLayout on which you can apply animation and TextView Separately. So Whatever animation you applied on FrameLayout will not reflect in TextView.

Comment: There is a TextView and a Button in the layout. They are in the same position and have different widths. When one is displayed, the other is not displayed. The scale animation is used for the appearance and disappearance of the button. I want to make it appear more natural.